# ocaml error: This expression has type inst/47646 list but an expression was expected of type inst/48106 list

Tags: ocaml

```
type inst =
  | InstRR of opcode * reg * reg
  | InstRI of opcode * reg * imm;;
```

the error i get is :  This expression has type `inst/47646` list
       but an expression was expected of type `inst/48106` list
       Type `inst/47646` is not compatible with type `inst/48106` 
but the list i'm sending is of type inst it's a list of `InstRI` and `InstRR`
what could be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OCaml error with types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441854/ocaml-error-with-types)

Answer (score 2):

The following minimal example shows how to reproduce the problem you're having:

```
# type t = A;;
type t = A
# let x = A;;
val x : t = A
# type t = A;;
type t = A
# let y = A;;
val y : t = A
# x = y;;
Error: This expression has type t/1029 but an expression was expected of type
         t/1026
```

The number you see appended to the type name is used by the toplevel to disambiguate between distinct types having the same name. When you define a type in the toplevel, it hides any previously defined type with the same name, even if the type definition remains identical. To work around this, you only need to reevaluate all your statements.

Comment: what do you mean reevaluate all my statements?

Comment: If you have your various type and value declarations in a file, you need to reload the file. Otherwise, you have to type the declarations again, making sure that all functions that take `inst` are typed in after the *last* definition of `inst`. You don't want to be passing `inst`s using a second definition of `inst` to functions that expect `inst`s from a first definition of `inst`.

Comment: Thank you @martin-jambon you for your valuable editing!